# How to calculate weight of an object on an angled surface?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

What formula could I use to calculate the apparent weight of an object on an angled surface, e.g, a 100 kg box on the side of a hill at 10° given that the measuring instrument is also at that same 10° from level?

Comment: You need to think first that force is a vector. On a plane surface you have the weight as you read it in the scale. If you have it on a tilted surface, then the weight is "distributed" differently along different directions.

Answer (score 1):

Note :- reading of a instrument like weighing machine is not the actual weight of the object placed on it but the normal force applied but the object  on the scale .[image]  so now from the image we can see for equilibrium of the block normal to incline we have $ R = mg cos( \theta) $  hence the reding would be not equal to the weight of the object but a little less than it. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The apparent weight is just the normal force. Using geometry you can figure out that the normal force is given by $$F = mg\cos\theta.$$